# Parllel processing in php

Tags: php, concurrency, multiprocessing, multitasking

I am developing a cakephp3.0 web application. In that there is an upload video page is there. User can upload n number of videos of max 2gb. So I am uploading the videos as multiparts but in the sequential order. Like iterating using a for loop first video will come , then second video will come but the problem is that user need to wait a long for to complete this uploading task and get response. I want to do this uploading in a concurrent way like uploading more than one videos at the same time in different queue's. so that the uploading can be completed very fast. Is there any way to do multiprocessing in php.

Comment: One TCP connection is supposed to max out the available upload bandwidth between the client and your server. Uploading several files in parallel *should* not be faster than uploading them sequentially; each upload will simply be slower. Maybe in practice you'll see a *little* bit of a difference, but it shouldn't become "very fast" all of a sudden by switching from sequential to parallel uploads. That would only make a difference if the server's bandwidth was the bottleneck and parallel uploads would distribute across multiple servers. But likely the client is the bottleneck anyway.

Comment: Like @deceze said - you max out the bandwith. What do you think would happen if you were to upload 1 file using full upload speed versus uploading 10 files using full upload speed? You're still using full upload speed, whatever the case is, so why do you think anything would be faster and what does PHP have to do with it? It's even not responsible for receiving the file, web server is.

Comment: The problem is that when a user uploading so many videos if any other user tried to upload some other videos he also will be in the queue. so in order to avoid that a proper management is needed

Comment: Which web server allows only a single upload at a time…?! No, that is not an issue typically, unless you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @SenchuThomas you are drawing some wrong conclusions. What queue and why would some other user end up in a queue? I don't think you understand that there's actually no problem here.

Comment: @Mjh  As I am using multi part upload  with each chunk size of 100mb. So if my ram is of 1gb remaining 900mb will be un used at that time. so if I am able to use that reaming 900 mb to upload other files I can do the uploading more faster

Comment: No, you can't. Your RAM has nothing to do with uploading files. Your internet connection's bandwith does. Speed of transferring files doesn't depend on YOUR RAM, it depends on the bandwith of your internet connection. And that bandwith gets used just like deceze explained. You seem very confused.

Answer (score 1):

If you're uploading in parallel, you're splitting the client upload / server download speed into the number of parallel uploads. If you upload sequentially it will max out this speed on both sides for a single file. So your end result will be exactly the same.

However if you're doing a form submission, your user's browser will be indeed locked until all of the uploads succeed.  You need the user to stay there regardless, so that's fine, but there should be some UX solution that will tell the user what is going on.

That's why you should probably intercept your form submission and do each upload (sequentially) with javascript. Then you could add some UX to also let the user see some progress.

You can find more info on uploading with JS here:

https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#FileReader-interface